# Mandatory fields javascript

Tags: javascript

I found the folowing code, for a non-refreshing form contact, and I would like all the fields to be mandatory. Can anyone please help? I have no knowledge at all of javascript. Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#submitBtn" ).click(function( event ) {
    //values
    var name=document.getElementById('name').value;
    var email=document.getElementById('email').value;
    var phone=document.getElementById('phone').value;
    var message=document.getElementById('message').value;
    var dataString = {"name": name, "email":email, "phone": phone, "message":message}

    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"submitForm.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(html) {
            $('#feedback').html(html);
        }
    });
  event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

html

```
<form id="contact" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="sr-only">Nume</label>
                        <input id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nume" type="text" tabindex="1" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                        <input id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="phone" class="sr-only">Telefon</label>
                        <input id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefon" type="tel" tabindex="3" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message" class="sr-only">Mesaj</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Mesaj" tabindex="5" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="submit" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary" value="Trimite" type="submit">
                    </div>
                    <div id="feedback"></div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: So add validation and make sure they have values before sending.

Comment: just add required html attribute to your form. or check for null value before submitting form

Comment: can use HTML `required` or [JS validation](http://formvalidation.io/getting-started/)

Comment: epascarello, exactly, that's what I need.

Comment: @HegedusLotzy Do some research.... lol, it really is not not that hard.  A simple search for "javascript validation" gives 3 tutorials as the results on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML5 Validation here, `required` attribute.

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

You need to use `submit` event instead of `click`.

For example, if this your HTML:

```
<form id="contact">
    ...
```

Then you should attach

```
$("#contact").on("submit", function(){

    // Make AJAX Call here

});
```

Comment: @HegedusLotzy you need to input tags inside a form tag.

Comment: @HegedusLotzy can you share your HTML?

Comment: @void, no, it is because OP uses onclick on the button

Answer (score 0):

First, use the form's onSubmit event, not the submit button onClick. Second, use the `required` attribute, so your input fields will look something like this:

```
<input id="name" required>
```

Comment: Please note my comment about using the form's onSubmit event. The onClick event will trigger regardless of the required fields.